# Python - add variables including NaN

Tags: python

Example Dataset:

```
var1  var2  result
1     4     5
2     NaN   2
3     5     8
NaN   6     6
NaN   NaN   NaN
```

I would like to create a new variable by summing var1 & var2, as seen above. However - I don't want to just replace NaN in var2 with 0s.

This question was closed because someone pointed me towards a question that would fill var2 with zeros. I need the sum to work if either are NaN, and if var1 & var2 are both NaN, I need the resulting new variable to by NaN. I feel like this wasn't answered by the question duplicate I was directed to.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try: `v3 = v1 + (v2 if not math.isnan(v2) else 0)`

Answer (score 3):

A straightforward solution:

```
def mysum(var1, var2):
    if math.isnan(var1):
        return var2
    else:
        if math.isnan(var2):
            return var1
        else:
            return var1 + var2
```

If you want it to support a list of variables:

```
def mysum(vars):
    vars = [x for x in vars if not math.isnan(x)]  # delete all nans
    if vars:
        return sum(vars)
    else:
        return float('nan')
```

Note: [numpy happens to have a function `nansum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html) which does exactly that, but its behavior was later changed for the case of all `nan`s, so better define your own one.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify `min_count=1` in pandas [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
df['result'] = df[['var1','var2']].sum(axis=1, min_count=1)
```

Result:

```
   var1  var2  result
0   1.0   4.0     5.0
1   2.0   NaN     2.0
2   3.0   5.0     8.0
3   NaN   6.0     6.0
4   NaN   NaN     NaN
```

From docs:

> **min_countint, default 0**
> The required number of valid values to perform the operation. If fewer than min_count non-NA values are present the result will be NA.